# How to calculate font-size according to size of div using js

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-size

I have dynamic size `div` element.

I have size w, h if this `div` and I want to calculate maximum font-size.

How can I calculate maximum `font-size` (css property)? Only using javascript.

Comment: `I have size w, h if this div and I want to calculate maximum font-size.` Obviously, it's the height of the div. Which you already have. I don't see the point of this question.

Comment: So, when the div height is `200px`, I can set `font-size: 200px`?

Comment: you can use setInterval to check the height of the div regularly and adjust the font accordingly or if u know what changes the div's size then on its occurrence change the fontsize